# Confirm is prompt one by one on users screen javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm making project using socket.io nodejs,When server emits to all users in a room, In client side there is confrim javascript function,Which is being called one by one in all users screen,below is client side code,

```
socket.on('resetcount',function(){
    if (confirm('Do you want to reset board?')) {
        socket.emit('count',roomnumber);
    }
});
```

Is it possible that it will prompt at the same time in all users screen, Or socket.io server works this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exactly the same time is very difficult. If you fire an event, you are stuck with rendering time of the client (browser/internet connection /hardware). But if approximately(+- couple of sec) the same time is acceptable for you. Then socket.io is the way to go

Comment: Actually in this next prompt will not come until user selects ok or cancel,So this means that until socket.on() is executed server will not respond to other user,am i right?